# Who wrote the Ritva on Gittin?

Tags: history, jewish-books, rishonim, authorship, ritva

I've heard many things about the author of "Ritva on Gittin." It might have been the Ritva, it might not have been. There's also the "חידושים מכתב יד," which some ascribe to the Ritva, while others don't. (see, eg, [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38155/5323))

How have people accurately determined the authorship of these works?

Comment: I don't think this is a [duplicate](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38137/5323), because (1) it's more specific (2) it asks a different question in the second question: how was authorship verified?

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15520/759

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed at length in the hakdamah to the Mosad R' Kook Ritva, and in R' Avrohom Shoshana's Ritva published by Ofeq Institute.

In brief, the old Ritva acc. to some is ר' כרשכש. The new one acc. to some is Ritva, acc. to R' Shoshanah it's mostly the Ramah with some others. It's more complicated than that, but that's the Cliff Notes answer.

Comment: One correction, there's a misspelling in my answer. It's רבינו קרשקש.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Hope you stick around.

Comment: There's an Ofeq version of Ritva on Gittin!? I can't find it anywhere. Can I ask what the ISBN is so I can try to track it down?